# Block UI: how to show the blocking image after page load

Tags: blockui, jquery-blockui

I am using BlockUI for my web app. On my page, I have

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI); 
    });
```

The page uses Ajax to get data at page load, and I am able to see the spinning image as Ajax indicator.

After the page load, I have buttons and clicking on them invokes Ajax calls to get data and update part of the page. However, in these operations, I am not able to see the spinning image that I can see at page load.

How can I show blocking image/indicator after page load? Anything I did is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code ;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#yourDivName').delay(4000).hide();
```

});

After the 4 second your div is hiding with this way.

Atakan.

Comment: Atakan, thanks for chiming in. I have to show an visual indicator to users and I cannot set specific time regarding how long the visual indicator lasts because fetching data via Ajax depends many factors.